# 1215 General error: Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with an already created foreign key constraint:

Error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key 
constraint (SQL: alter table `league_seasons` add 
constraint `league_seasons_league_id_foreign` foreign key (`league_id`)
 references `leagues` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

This is league table

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('leagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->increments('increment_id');
            $table->string('type')->nullable();
            $table->integer('legacy_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('country_id')->nullable();
    }
```

And this is league_seasons table

```
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('league_seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->increments('increment_id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('league_id');
            $table->string('is_current_season')->nullable();
            $table->string('current_round_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('current_stage_id')->nullable();
            App\Helpers\DbExtender::defaultParams($table, true);
        });

        Schema::table('league_seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('league_id')->references('id')->on('leagues')->onDelete('cascade');

        });

    }
```

I've tried swaping unSignedInteger, BigInteger but none of them seem to be working. 
Any idea why is it acting like this? 
Thank you

Comment: You need an index on the `id` that you want to use as a foreign key and they both have to be be either `unsigned` or `signed`. Try `->unsignedInteger('id')->index()` on the `leagues` table and `->unsignedInteger('league_id')->index()` on the `league_sesons` table. It's a bit confusing as `increments()` (which people usually use for the `id`) sets the PK and therefore creates the index for you.

Comment: Can you add more details with this questions? Like which Laravel version you are using etc..

Comment: @AshokDhaudk 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @repat pointed out, adding unSignedInteger with index() on both table worked for me.

final league table:

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('leagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id')->index();
            $table->increments('increment_id');
            $table->string('type')->nullable();
            $table->integer('legacy_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('country_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
    }
```

final league_seasons table:

```
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('league_seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->increments('increment_id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('league_id')->index();
            $table->string('is_current_season')->nullable();
            $table->string('current_round_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('current_stage_id')->nullable();
            App\Helpers\DbExtender::defaultParams($table, true);
        });

        Schema::table('league_seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('league_id')->references('id')->on('leagues')->onDelete('cascade');

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create `Foreign key` the data type for the `child column` must match the `parent column` exactly. For example, since `leagues.id` is an `integer`, `league_seasons.league_id` also needs to be an `integer`, not a `unsignedInteger`.

> **So change**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('league_id');
```

> **to**

```
$table->integer('league_id');
```